# In Python, how can square-shaped images be saved using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My goal is to create a number of matplotlib plots and then to arrange them in a large array. For this purpose, I need to ensure that the output images of matplotlib plots are square. How can this be done?

Here's a segment of my code:

```
figure = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
figure.suptitle(label, fontsize = 20)
#figure.set_size_inches(19.7, 19.7)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(
    variable_1_values,
    variable_2_values,
    s          = marker_size,
    c          = "#000000",
    edgecolors = "none",
    label      = label,
)
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(label_x)
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(label_y)
legend = matplotlib.pyplot.legend(
    loc            = "center left",
    bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5),
    fontsize       = 10
)
print("save {filename}".format(filename = filename))
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(
    filename,
    bbox_extra_artists = (legend,),
    bbox_inches        = "tight",
    dpi                = 700
)
```

I know how to set the figure to square, what I need is the output image set to square. This would be conceptually as simple as taking the default output image and then extending its background as necessary to make the image square.

Comment: do not use `bbox_inches='tight'` which 'shrink wraps' the saved figure to the bounding box of the artists in the figure.

Comment: @tcaswell Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I've given it a try and it does seem to help (the images seem to match the aspect ratio set for the figure), but then I run into problems with the axes labels going outside the image bounds (http://i.imgur.com/Obw8Hfg.png). Would you have any thoughts on how to address this? I'm dealing with a large number of images so I can't really change the format of the axes numbers individually.

Comment: `figure.tight_layout()` (which re-arranges/resizes the axes)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it produces a 600x600 pixel png image for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(size=1000)
b = np.random.normal(size=1000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

plt.plot(a,b,'g.')
plt.xlabel("x axis label")
plt.ylabel("y axis label")
plt.title("Random numbers in a scatter plot")

fig.savefig("test.png")
```